# how to rename folder and its all sub folder using ssis

Tags: vb.net, ssis

In file System task there is no option to rename a folder.The option is to rename file.
I do understand we can achieve renaming of multiple fils using a for each loop and file system task.
Is there any wayto rename a folder and all it's sub folder using any of the tasks in ssis

Answer (score 4):

File System Task is the tool you want. A Move Directory is the same as a Rename.

[image: Example]

Configure it as such. I prefer variables as it makes my packages cleaner

[image]

You could of course get the same results by running an Execute Task command and using the `rename` command

> Renames a file or files.
>
> RENAME [drive:][path]filename1 filename2. REN [drive:][path]filename1
>   filename2.
>
> Note that you cannot specify a new drive or path for your destination
>   file.

Finally, if you just like making things hard, you could use a Script Task and leverage the System.IO.Directory's [Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx) method but on behalf of everyone who has to maintain novel approaches to solving problems, just use the `File System Task`

Comment: Thank you.If there is a need to move and rename a folder and all it's subfolders..the new name wou;ld be like oldname_<todaysdate>.How to do this